# Excel Power Pivot - connect day with dates

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax

I am trying to create a pivot table in excel. I have the following data: person's name and surname, the range of dates during which they were on vacation, the starting date, and the number of vacation days. I would like to create a summary where I would have months in rows and then people. In the column headers, I would like to have days - from 1 to 31. In the appropriate places, I would like to have marked days worked. Example: Julia X was on vacation from 01.01.2022 to 05.01.2022. I would like the columns with values 01,02,03,04,05 to have marks. How can I do this?

I have created an additional table where I have values of days from 1 to 31. I also have all the dates in the year from 01.01.2022 to 31.12.2022, and each date also has the given week. I tried to merge them, but I am failing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTXpp.png)

Comment: So are you testing if 01.01.2022 is in the range 01.01.2022 to 05.01.2022 ?

Comment: Yes, and I want to make some marks below the columns